# jQueryrotate How to rotate more than 1 image by a cursor

Tags: jquery-rotate

I am trying jqueryrotate plugin and simply rotate given image by a cursor. It works 
but my question is when I used 2 images with same ID class  
rotate only work at first image, how to do make it work separately

```
http://jsfiddle.nXt/8xwqdk71/
```

I will use for many images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two or more objects / elements with the same `id`. Modify your code to target a class instead.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" class="image">

var value = 0
$(".image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=90;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     } 
});

.image{
  margin:100px 100px;
}
```

**EDIT**: In addition, you need to have a rotation-value that isn't globally shared between all the images. The above will give you some interesting spinning effects when you have multiple images.

An updated version is at: http://jsfiddle.net/0nwvt303/

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" class="image" rotation=0>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" class="image" rotation=0>

$(".image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            currRotation = ($(this).attr("rotation") * 1) + 90;
            $(this).attr("rotation", currRotation);
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:currRotation });
        }
     } 
});
```